# Where is the error that I'm not finding in this Python code?

Tags: python, variables, input, syntax-error

I cannot find the error. I would much appreciate some help! Thank you in advance.

"""
This program asks the user for three ingredients,
three amounts, and a number of servings, and
determines how much of each ingredient is needed
to serve the specified number of servings.
"""

```
ingredient_one = input("What is the first ingredient?: ")
ing_one_oz = int(input("How many ounces of this ingredient?: ")

ingredient_two = input("What is the second ingredient?: ")
ing_two_oz = int(input("How many ounces of this ingredient?: ")

ingredient_three = input("What is the third ingredient?: ")
ing_three_oz = int(input("How many ounces of this ingredient?: ")



servings_amt = int(input("How many servings would you like?: ")

ing_one_oz = ing_one_oz * servings_amt
ing_two_oz = ing_two_oz * servings_amt
ing_three_oz = ing_three_oz * servings_amt

print("In order to make " + str(servings_amt) + " servings of your recipe, you will need " + str(ing_one_oz) + " ounces of " /
+ str(ingredient_one) + ", " + str(ing_two_oz) + " ounces of " + str(ingredient_two) + ", and " + str(ing_three_oz) /
+ " ounces of " + str(ingredient_three) + ".")
```

The output displays a syntax error on line 3 where it starts with variable ingredient_two.
Line 1 was already passed as "correct", but line 3 does not, even though they are practically the same.

Comment: You have mismatched parentheses on a number of lines, e.g. `int(input("How many ounces of this ingredient?: ")` is missing a closing parenthesis. Also, consider using [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) for string formatting.

Comment: Your mistake is a typo. You missed the second `)` at a lot of places. I suggest you use an IDE like PyCharm to catch these.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a python expert but

```
int(input("How many ounces of this ingredient?: ")
```

doesn't need a second ")" ?

Answer (score 2):

Your error is in line 2.  You need an extra parentheses at the end of ing_one_oz

```
ing_one_oz = int(input("How many ounces of this ingredient?: ")
```

Python is funny about picking up errors that occur on previous lines.

Answer (score 1):

The error is at line #2,#4,#6,#7 i.e. ing_one_oz, ing_two_oz, ing_three_oz, servings_amt. Close the parenthesis where ever you are typecasting your input to 'int'